# Cardinality of point preimages of connected toplogical spaces under covering maps

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and $p:Y\to X$ be a covering map. Assuming $X$ is connected, show that for all $x_{1},x_{2}\in X$, $\Big|p^{-1}\big(\{x_{1}\}\big)\Big|=\Big|p^{-1}\big(\{x_{2}\}\big)\Big|$. The idea is to let $\left|p^{-1}\left(\{x_{0}\}\right)\right|=\lambda$ for some $x_{0}\in X$ and show that the set $A=\left\{ x\in X:\left|p^{-1}\left(\{x_{0}\}\right)\right|=\lambda\right\} $ is open and closed. However, I have no idea how to do this. Any hints would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521827/suppose-pe-to-b-is-a-covering-map-and-b-is-connected-prove-that-if-p-1

Comment: It does! Thank you very much. I should have looked at the similar questions more thoroughly.